# ResultSet didn't bring all data from Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I have a table in my DB with 6,312,391 registers. I was exporting the data to many files with 2 million registers each, but for some reason in the last file not all the registers were written as I expected. I have 3 files with 2M regs and the last one with just 312,355 instead of 312,391.

What could have happened? My java routine to get the data is as follows:

```
public void generarArchivoPorRegistros(int registersPerFile) {

    CallableStatement cs = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    connect();
    try {
        cs = connection.prepareCall("{call pec_pec_proc(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.execute();

        rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);

        int numberOfFile = 1;
        int registersWrote = 0;
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("SEDESOL_" + (numberOfFile * registersPerFile/(1000000)) + "M.txt"));
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (registersWrote == registersPerFile) {
                    bw.close();
                    numberOfFile++;
                    bw = new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("SEDESOL_" + (numberOfFile * registersPerFile/(1000000)) + "M.txt"));
                    registersWrote = 0;
                }
                bw.write(rs.getString(1));
                bw.newLine();
                registersWrote++;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your while loop you need to close the last BufferedWriter. Probably it wasn't flushed out when your program exits.

Comment: I think you're 99.99% right hehe, let me try it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks it was that little thing.